# Non-Linear combination approximation and optimization

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

I am looking to find a way to a way to solve for a combination of optical filters that match a transmittance dataset that I have. I need to solve for the exponents x,y,z...n (they can be zero) as well as quantify how close I got to the target transmittance curve across it's domain (300-700nm). Here the exponential variables represent the number of times each filter is chosen and there is a .96 (loss) in the gap between filters.

$$T_{total} = T_1^{x}*T_2^{y}*\cdots *T_{46}^{n}(0.96^{[(x+y+⋯+n) -1]})  $$

I was going to do $X= A^{-1}*B$ in matlab but I think that only works for forms like  $T = aX + bY \cdots nZ$

I am really unfamiliar with this type of math and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the problem by taking a logarithm, which will give you something like:

$\begin{eqnarray}\log T_{total} & = & x \log T_1 + y \log T_2 + \ldots + (x + y + \ldots - 1) \log 0.96 \\
\log T_{total} + \log 0.96 & = & x (\log T_1 + \log 0.96) + y (\log T_2 + \log 0.96) + \ldots \end{eqnarray}$

And then you can just do a linear fit on the values of $\log T_{total} + \log 0.96$ against $(\log T_1 + \log 0.96, \log T_2 + \log 0.96, \ldots)$.

Comment: These exponents represent the number of times that we use a particular filter. Is there a way that I can (mathematically) restrict the values to whole real numbers or do I just throw away solutions that contain fractions? We are also limiting the total number of filters to 4 and no more than 2 of any one type. We have a spatial limitation with the simulator and with 46 filters, it is a lot of data to crunch. I was planning on doing some nested for loops.

Comment: Solving for integers is harder, especially since you'll probably be vulnerable to rounding errors. If you've got enough data points, then your best chance is probably to fit the model like I described and round the coefficients to the nearest integer.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the answer is not unique? ie: more than one combination? does that show up as complex solutions or something else?

Comment: If you run it as a linear model like this, then it will only give a single solution. You could run it as an integer satisfiability problem which is computationally quite a bit harder and will definitely need you to put some tolerances in for error on the data points.

Comment: I used this method and got a set of values for each of the 41 values that represent wavelength. ![https://ibb.co/5Mxr2gm]

Comment: https://ibb.co/5Mxr2gm - for some reason you have to add the "https://" I just picked the solution set that represented 410 nm and the results are way off. Some of the solutions where selecting over 100 filters.

Comment: I know the total number of filters should be around 5 or less because of the air-gap loss which multiplies the whole thing by $(0.96)^{n-1}$ where n is the total number of filters.